# Wilcoxon matched pairs signed rank test difference in medians but insignificant?

Tags: interpretation, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, median

I am trying to understand the result of the Wilcoxon test I used on my small sample. For one measure there is a big difference in the medians between the two conditions. However, the result is highly insignificant! Whereas in other instances the difference isn't that big and it is significant. How do you interpret that?

Comment: Can you show data to illustrate?

Comment: median in cond. 1  was .3 and in cond. 2 median was .37 sig. .046, the other result  med. in cond 1.  was .24 and in cond 2 was .34, and sig. .41

Comment: Should I just consider the T and the Z ?

Comment: I was hoping to see actual data. Your summaries don't get to issues I need to discuss. Doing my best with fake data in my Answer. // Don't use t test unless data are normal or sample size is moderate and data are nearly normal. Don't use z test unless population variance of paired differences is normal and population variance is known.

Answer (score 5):

First, I assume (because you said 'signed rank') that this is a **paired design**.
Then the test involves the differences between the pairs. If you are looking
at the difference in medians between conditions 1 and 2, that is not relevant.
It is the median of the paired differences that matters.

Second, you have said nothing about **sample sizes**, except that they are 'small'.
The smallest possible number of pairs to get a significant result at the 5%
level is $n = 5.$ If one of the experiments has 5 pairs and the other has 15,
then the difference in results may be due mainly to difference in sample sizes.

Finally, **consistency among pairs matters.** Suppose Experiment 1 has large, but inconsistent, paired differences
and Experiment 2 has smaller, but mostly consistent, paired differences.
Then Experiment 2 may reject the null hypothesis of no difference between
conditions, while the first experiment does not.

Here are examples, starting with Experiment 1:

```
x1 = c(10, 11, 20, 57, 40)  # mostly 'small'
x2 = c( 9, 13, 30, 35, 73)  # mostly 'large'
median(x1);  median(x2)
[1] 20
[1] 30
x1 - x2
[1]   1  -2 -10  22 -33     # inconsistent signs of paired differences

wilcox.test(x1, x2, pair=T)

        Wilcoxon signed rank test

data:  x1 and x2
V = 5, p-value = 0.625      # not significant at 5% level
alternative hypothesis: 
  true location shift is not equal to 0
```

Experiment 2:

```
y1 = c(1.1, 1.2, 1.2, 2.8, 1.5, 1.6)
y2 = c(1.2, 2.3, 1.7, 3.1, 1.9, 1.8)  # consistently larger
median(y1); median(y2)
[1] 1.35
[1] 1.38

wilcox.test (y1, y2, pair=T)

        Wilcoxon signed rank test

data:  y1 and y2
V = 0, p-value = 0.03125               # significant result at 5% level
alternative hypothesis: 
  true location shift is not equal to 0
```

Comment: Sorry, I have two conditions and 10 observations/measures in each of them. First condition with gesture, second without. I am looking at the amount of filled pauses in each of those conditions. gesture no gesture I don't know how to put the data in the comment here so it's clear. But in this case the medians are different, however, in the case of five subjects there were more pauses in the gestures than in the no gesture, and also 5 subjects showed opposite tendency, would that effect the result? Sorry, my understanding of stats is very bad.

Comment: would you be able to tell me which value in the spss represents  the median of the paired differences ? thank you so much for your help

Comment: If you have five positive differences out of ten, and five negative ones, I'd say you are not going to be able to reject the null hypothesis. I'd guess the median difference must be around 0. That is, it seems you have no evidence that gestures make a difference. (If you toss a coin ten times and get half heads and half tails, then you have no reason to say the coin is biased.) Without seeing the data or the SPSS output I can't say more than that.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I really appreciate it. I don't seem to be able to put the data or spss output here without it being all muddled up. Thank you again.